# JPA: Column 'AdressId' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

i'm trying to persist school entity that have a unidirectional oneToOne relationship with Adresse, but i'm getting `Column 'AdressId' cannot be null`, note that MySQL DB generate ids for School and Adresse  here is my code:
in JSF, when submit button is clicked the createSchool method is invoked.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SchoolAdd extends BaseBacking implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String INSCRIPTION_RETURN = "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
private static final String RB_Name = "Bundle.messages";
private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND = "user.not.found";

private String userEmail;

private User user;
private School school;
private Adresse adress;

@EJB
private SchoolPr schoolPr;

@EJB
private UserPr userPr;


public SchoolAdd() {
    school = new School();
    adress = new Adresse();

    school.setPhoneNumbers(new HashMap<PhoneTypeSchool, String>());
}

public String createSchool() {
    userEmail = getRequest().getUserPrincipal().getName();
    System.out.println(userEmail);
    try {
        user = userPr.getUserByEmail(userEmail);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(ResourceBundleLoader.getBundle(RB_Name, USER_NOT_FOUND)));//DEL DEBUG
    }
    school.setUser(user);
    school.setAdresse(adress);
    System.out.println("1: " + adress.getCountry());
    System.out.println("2: " + school.getAdresse().getCountry());
    schoolPr.createSchool(school);

    return INSCRIPTION_RETURN;
}+getters & stters for school & adress
```

School Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "school", name = "school")
public class School implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private BigInteger id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "adressId", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Adresse adresse;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date creationDate;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="SCHOOL_PHONE")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@MapKeyColumn(name="PHONE_TYPE")
@Column(name="PHONE_NUM")
private Map<PhoneTypeSchool, String> phoneNumbers;

@Column(name = "JOIN_DATE")
private Timestamp joinDate;
```

Adresse Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "school", name = "adress")
public class Adresse implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private BigInteger id;

private String country;

private String state;

private String city;

private String street;

private String number;

private String zip;
```

UPDATE:
if @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) is used I get:

```
Avertissement: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):         org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mysql.sequence' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
```

Comment: Why is the @generatedValue on Adresse.id commented out?

Comment: "note that MySQL DB generate ids for School and Adresse" i would say that this is obviously not the case ... Have you had success with the @GeneratedValue not commented out?

Comment: @generatedValue is commented because I get this exception: Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mysql.sequence' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146

Comment: it ask for a sequence table for auto generation!!!!??

Comment: GenerationType.AUTO means you have the sequence table, so you need to  SchemaGeneration for the table to be created.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Sequencing

Comment: user2026214: I didn't understand, what do you mean by SchemaGeneration. + I don't have any sequence table. please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change it from AUTO to IDENTITY and now it works.